# nth permutation of a vector in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, vector, permutation

Suppose I have a vector of integers like this:

```
A = [1 2 3]
```

What I need is nth permutation of vector `A`. As we now a vector of `n` numbers has `n!` permutation, For example some permutation of `A` is:

```
[1 2 3]
[1 3 2]
[2 1 3]
[2 3 1]
...
```

Is there any built-in function for calculating nth permutation? if not, can anyone please offer me a efficient algorithm for calculate it? Any suggestion would be highly appreciated

Comment: perms([1 2 3])? For N, perms(1:N), I think might work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my answer from @Divakar comment (special thanks to @Divakar)
What I need is:

```
% this my vector 1, 2, 3 , ..., N
A = 1 : N;
P = perms(A);

% nth permutation of A is nth row of P
nthPerm = P(n, :);
```

Answer (score 0):

If `A` is just the trivial sequence `1:N`, as @Divakar said, the command

```
perms(1:N)
```

produces the permutations you need.

If `A` is an array whose content is generic and whose length is `N`, `perms` can be used to obtain the indices allowing the permutations, i.e.

```
A_permutations = A(perms(1:N))
```

Example:

given

```
A =

 3     7     9



  A(perms(1:3))

   9     7     3
   9     3     7
   7     9     3
   7     3     9
   3     7     9
   3     9     7
```

Answer (score 0):

perms(v) works for the n! case,

http://www.mathworks.de/matlabcentral/fileexchange/11462-npermutek/content/npermutek.m
works for the n^n or n^k case.

Answer (score 0):

If you like doing stuff in less lines of code, you can also do:

```
A=1:N;
nthPerm=getfield(perms(A),{n,A})
```

Note that this is only valid if `A=1,2,3,...,N`. For different values of `A`, you would have to change this into:

```
A=1:N;
nthPerm=getfield(perms(A),{n,1:length(A)})
```